# Setting options to a socket.io-client connection

Tags: angularjs, sockets, socket.io

I have a socket.io server set with node.js, and a client - manager set inside of the angular application. I'm using socket.io-client library to connect. I'm passing it to controller with angular-socket-io:

```
app.factory('mySocket', function (socketFactory) {
   return socketFactory();
});

app.factory('socket', ['mySocket', '$rootScope', socket]);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'socket', MainController]);
```

My server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('welcome', { message: 'Welcome!', id: socket.id });
    socket.on('i am client', console.log);
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
   console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And essential client service:

```
  var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
   console.log(socket);

// Add a connect listener
socket.on('connect',function() {
  console.log('Client has connected to the server!');
  socket.emit('i am client', "hi!");

  socket.on('welcome', console.log);
});
```

I just couldn't connect them (two separate projects running on different ports) until I forced uri to be http://localhost:3000 in the socket.io.js file...

So my question is: how can I set my uri or host and port in the options so it gets the right uri? Just sayin, that classics like

```
io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
```

are simply not working.

EDIT: Figured it out. In the main js file, where socketFactory() is launched, it has to be like that:

```
app.factory('mySocket', function (socketFactory) {

var myIoSocket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
  return socketFactory({ ioSocket: myIoSocket });
});
```

Comment: Try `var socket = io();`

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out :)